# Динамическое формирование имени копируемого файла

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Есть входные переменные, их последовательность и состав может быть любой: Счетчик, дата, Родитель и т.д. На основании набора переменных необходимо формировать новое имя файла. Набор переменных динамичен, сегодня Счетчик_Дата, а завтра Родитель_Дата_Счетчик. Набор передается в виде строки. Подскажите, пожалуйста, с алгоритмом, как решить эту задачу?

Comment: Никак не решить, потому что не ясно по каким правилам что должно формироваться.

Comment: На основании входных переменных, их всего три. Пользователь формирует только набор и последовательность.

Comment: И? Какое правило для формирования имени должно быть? Если вы предлагаете его придумать - так и напишите и используйте хэш от строки.

Comment: Я приведу пример. "Дата, Счетчик". Имя файла будет 19072017_1, последующего файла 19072017_2. Если "Родитель, Счетчик", то к примеру History_3... Вы понимаете мою мысль?

Comment: Ну так и сделайте ```var filename = $"{parent}_{counter}.txt";``` что мешает? Вот вы пишете "сегодня то-то, а завтра то-то": ну так и поставите завтра ещё один if, это сложно? Вы _сегодня_ знаете, какой будет _завтра_ алгоритм или сами не в курсе? Если не знаете -- то и мы тем более. Дадут завтра новое ТЗ, сделаете новый билд. Знаете -- вписывайте в вопрос, чтобы телепатов не приглашать.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов совершено не понимаю. По какому правилу "Дата" превращается в "19072017", а "Родитель" в "History"?

Comment: Ok. Есть папка с подпапками, в которой хранятся файлы. Родитель - это папка, в которой хранится файл, Дата - дата создания файла. Мне нужно скопировать их по другому пути с новыми именами. Правило формирования нового имени задает пользователь в виде строки.

Comment: Телепаты предполагают, что вам нужна шаблонизация. Т.е. у вас есть некоторая переменная, допустим, взятая из конфиг-файла (update: увидел новый комментарий, значит введённая пользователем). И допустим она  может содержать символы %%Дата%% или %%CompName%%, которые вы будете заменять на текущую дату или имя компьютера. Описываете набор переменных, доступных пользователю в документации, кодите, наслаждаетесь. Не то?

Comment: ))) Телепаты не верно предположили, я выше написал немного лучше.

Comment: Перечитал, но ничего не понял. Добавил свой голос за закрытие, но возможно кто-то успеет прочитать комментарии и угадает лучше. ЗЫ Не обижайтесь, но хорошо сформулированный вопрос -- половина ответа.

Comment: Не обидно, спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Берете ваш шаблон и заменяете поля на нужные вам значения:

```
var template = "Родитель_Дата_Счетчик";
var result = template.Replace("Родитель", parent);
result = result.Replace("Дата", date);
result = result.Replace("Счетчик", counter);
```

Будет работать независимо от шаблона. Главное все возможные типы полей обрабатывать.